# keep bathroom fan running for a few minutes after power off

Tags: capacitor, fan

What is the best way to keep the bathroom fan running after cutting the power to it? I assume a capacitor can be used, but which one should I use and how do I connect it?

Comment: And is it some AC fan or DC driven???? However forget capacitor..

Comment: @perilbrain yes it's AC driven 220V. just your average exhaust fan

Comment: Is there some reason you can't use a [timer switch](http://www.lowes.com/pd_207236-14-57W_0__?productId=3128137) like everybody else?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[This module](http://www.ebay.ca/itm/Timer-Delay-Off-Switch-0-10-minutes-500W-110V-220VAC-/140380650827)

[image]

uses the switch as input and replaces it in the circuit with a relay. After the switch is switched off the relay remains on for a programmable time between 0 and 10 minutes.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The best way to keep it running for a few minutes would be to use a suitably large battery (and inverter assuming it's mains AC powered)

If power is still present (the above assumes not as your question says "after cutting the power to it, rather than "after flicking the switch") then a relay and timer is the way to go.

Even a huge capacitor won't provide anywhere near the storage required.

Comment: what about a relay of some sort?

Comment: Yes, a suitably rated relay with simple timer would work okay - I imagine you can buy this type of thing commercially.